# C# what is the necessary library for PostMessage?

Tags: c#, keydown, postmessage

I am trying to simulate a keypress in C# and I'm getting these errors:

```
Error   2   The name 'WM_KEYDOWN' does not exist in the current context c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 28  52  HaxBot3
Error   5   The name 'WM_KEYDOWN' does not exist in the current context c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 29  52  HaxBot3
Error   8   The name 'WM_KEYDOWN' does not exist in the current context c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 30  52  HaxBot3
Error   9   The name 'VK_RIGHT' does not exist in the current context   c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 30  64  HaxBot3
Error   3   The name 'VK_CONTROL' does not exist in the current context c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 28  64  HaxBot3
Error   6   The name 'VK_ALT' does not exist in the current context c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 29  64  HaxBot3
Error   1   The name 'PostMessage' does not exist in the current context    c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 28  17  HaxBot3
Error   4   The name 'PostMessage' does not exist in the current context    c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 29  17  HaxBot3
Error   7   The name 'PostMessage' does not exist in the current context    c:\users\frk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HaxBot3\HaxBot3\Form1.cs 30  17  HaxBot3
```

and this is the code that gives the error:

```
public static void Forward()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("test");

            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 0);
                PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ALT, 0);
                PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT, 0);
            }
        }//Fprward
```

I guess I have to add something with `using System.(something)` but what? Thanks for help.

Comment: They should be windows message values. If you want a friendly enum for it, you'll have to write your own, or find one online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define these yourself.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, uint wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
public const uint VK_RIGHT = 27;
public const uint VK_CONTROL = 11;
public const uint VK_ALT = 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in User32.Dll.  You will need to specify it yourself. [Visit this PInvoke.net page on `PostMessage` for more information](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.postmessage).

Here's an example class assuming `Forward()` is in the class `MyClass`.

```
public static class MyClass
{
  public static void Forward()
  {
     /* snip */
  }

  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool PostMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```